# Select data in a datatable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datatable

I have configured a accessdb datasource in Microsoft Visual Studio, I have a dataset and a datatable called "Contractor". How can I search this data within a Form? More to the point how can I reference this table in code?

p.s. I've looked everywhere on google about datatables and all the examples show instantiating one locally, adding data and then searching for it not referencing one that already exists. So i have done my due diligence. Need help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you've tried so far? Are you using `OleDbDataReader`?

Comment: This is what my configuration is: connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Phase2.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" I made this through the wizard I just want to execute sql on the table "Contractor" in code though not DataGridViews

Comment: That's the connection string.  What about code to query (read) data from the database?

Comment: Yeh thats what i'm asking. How can I reference the tables I just imported.

Comment: @AidenRigby , use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374221/loading-access-db-table-to-datatable , to select data from table existing in file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the Database use the oledbCommand and OleDbDataReader

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                oledbConnection.Open();
                using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand getData = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand())
                {
                    getData.CommandText = "select * from table ";
                    getData.Connection = oledbConnection;
                    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader readData = getData.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (readData.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (readData.Read())
                            {
                              // get the data here
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

if you want to query a datatable use the asEnumerable() extension of datatable

```
 var readData = from currentRow in theDataTable.AsEnumerable()
 where currentRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
 select currentRow;
```