# How can i get the value of column field base on another column field

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

Im using Visual Studio C# and using Access as my database. I have two columns, `ItemCode` and `ProductName`. I want to auto input of the productname on its textbox whenever its itemcode was selected. how can I do this?

some codes:

```
 try
 {
 con.Open();
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");
 command.Connection = con;
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", txtItem.Text);

 OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.Read())//Update Item Code is already exist
    {
     .........
```

Feel free to edit my question and please be kind. thank you guys

Comment: What you mean by *auto input of the productname whenever its itemcode was selected*, I hope that you want to update the product_name  corresponds to the id in the `where` clause, isn't it?

Comment: yes i want to get the value of the product name and call it on my textbox which is corresponds to same row of that itemcode

Comment: I would load at least the ItemCode and ProductName pair into a [DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374221/loading-access-db-table-to-datatable), then [bind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660011/529282) the DataTable to whatever controls you use for displaying & selecting itemcode & productname. Remember you can bind [one data source to multiple controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713218/one-datasource-for-multiple-controls). Adjust the DisplayMember as needed for each controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

```
text_box.Text=reader["ProductName"].ToString();
```

You are filtering the rows by specifying the `ItemCode` in the `Where` clause, So The reader will contains the corresponding row/s that matches the specified code. What you need to do is Access the required column value by specifying the name as like the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting data from database, I prefer that use `OleDbDataAdapter`.
You can simply use:

```
string command = @"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Now, use `dt` :

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    //Error Message
else
    cmbTreatyTitle.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ProductName"].ToString();
```

I hope this is helpful.